# PHP How to prevent display of PHP file names through View Source

Tags: php, html

new to PHP. I created a form for login and noticed that when I right click on the page and choose view source I can see the `<form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

If my website URL is `www.logins.com` then the user can view the source, get the PHP file name, then go to `www.logins.com/login.php` and will be able to view the code of the PHP file. I am using PHP since I thought PHP codes are invisible to the user?

Comment: If you are new to PHP, where did you come from?

Comment: They cannot view the source code of the php file, they can view the *generated output* of the php file.

Comment: Sorry I'm actually from VBA and HTA. Thanks guys, I realized my problem but after posting this question. I was able to view the code of login.php because it's content does not include a PHP `<?php` yet

Comment: Probabely you have missed php opening tags `<?php` .if not, please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

They won't be able to view the PHP source, only the rendered HTML.  There's no easy way to protect this.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that makes sense now.:)